# Dynamic SQL select (MyBatis) return Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, select, orm, mybatis, ibatis

I've searched in the mybatis documentaion and in inet. But couldn't find the sollution.

**My goal is:** 
From myBatis dynamic SQL select return wether

```
Map <Strinng (Data Base Column), Object (Database Value)> or
List<Object> (Database Values)
```

**without creating pojo as representation of database table.**

It should looks like:

1) Dynamic SQL:

```
<select id="selectRecords" parameterType="Entry" resultType="Map">
 SELECT 
     <foreach item="column" index="index" collection="columns" separator=",">
     ${column} 
     </foreach> 
from ${tableName}
</select>
```

2) Parameter that I put into dynamic select:

```
public class Entry {

private String tableName;
private String[] columns;

//constructor
//getters, setters
```

}

3) Method that returns map:

```
Map<String, Object> selectRecords(Entry entry);
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: I can't find how can we select data into some collection. In the documentation, I saw that we can create java entity of representation of db table and use it as resultType. But can we use just collection as result of our select ?

Answer (score 0):

The very first example in tutorial shows an example of simple collection that is returned. [Here](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html),

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="int" resultType="hashmap">  
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE ID = #{id} </select>
```

> This statement is
>   called selectPerson, takes a parameter of type int (or Integer), and
>   returns a HashMap keyed by column names mapped to row values.

In this hashmap, Key-Value pairs are "ColumnName"-"Column's Value" pairs. No pojo is used. Your example code seems correct to me, you can print the errors if you get any.